# Why are CSS Imports being imported into other classes, and how can i resolve it? Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LightAccessPage from "./pages/LightAccessPage";

function App(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
                <Route path="/lap" component={LightAccessPage} exact />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App
```

As the title states, css from HomePage is being applied to LightAccessPage. IS this because when I import HomePage all the imports from it also transfer onto this file? IF so how can I fix this?

Comment: Without seeing the code for the **HomePage** and **LightAccessPage** components it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: https://paste.helpch.at/evomoxesiy.xml

https://paste.helpch.at/utajabanuc.js

Comment: Yes, you will have that problem if you have `h1` styled in **components/homepage/HomePage.css**. Importing a CSS file directly will make the styles global for the whole app. You can add unique class for `h1` in the `LightAccessPage` component, or use scoped CSS, such as [styled components](https://styled-components.com) provide.

Comment: Is there no way to make it so the CSS file only imports for the one page? It will be quite annoying to have to do it otherwi

Comment: You need then to make unique classes yourself. Don't style for example simply `h1` in your stylesheet, use a unique class name, e.g. `h1-home`, `h1-light-access`, and then in your components assign the `className` prop accordingly.